# Can you store the name of the list as a variable, instead of the contents of the list

Tags: python, list, variables

Context: python code running on Raspberrypi to animate some WS2801 RGB LEDs. To set the colour of the LEDs, you need to define R, G and B numeric values. I have set up some colour palettes to store a range of RGB colours that work well together and I want to randomly choose from this palette.

I have these palettes stored as two lists (lists truncated here to be succinct):

```
xmascolours = [
        (0, 137, 42),
        (243, 243, 243),
        ]

halloweencolours = [
        (21, 24, 24),
        (49, 49, 49),
        ]
```

I want to then randomly choose from one of these lists. If I simply do:

```
colour = random.choice(xmascolours)
```

This works fine. But to keep my code clear (since I regularly randomise the values to make the LEDs show a range of colours), I wanted to store the current palette I am using in another variable, so I only need to change that value once, rather then all the places I am calling random.choice. So, I tried to do this:

```
palette = 'xmascolours'
colour = random.choice(palette)
```

But this then seems to set colour to randomly chosen characters from the word palette! Clearly I am doing something wrong. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you want a dictionary, where you can store the name of the palette as the key, and the values as...values

Comment: `palette = xmascolours`? But really, as said above, a dict is the proper structure for named lookups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a dictionary of lists. That way you can load the list of palette you need by the palette name.

```
import random
colorScheme  = {}
colorScheme["xmascolours"] = [(0, 137, 42),(243, 243, 243)]
colorScheme["halloweencolours"] = [(21, 24, 24),(21, 24, 24)]
import pprint
print("Collection of colorSchemes:")
# You do not have to use pprint it just makes the list output look nice
pprint.pprint(colorScheme)

palette = colorScheme["xmascolours"]
print("All colors from xmascolors palette:")
print(palette)
colour = random.choice(palette) 
print("Random color from palette:")
print(colour)
```

**Output**

```
Collection of colorSchemes:
{'xmascolours': [(0, 137, 42), (243, 243, 243)], 'halloweencolours': [(21, 24, 24), (21, 24, 24)]}
All colors from xmascolors palette:
[(0, 137, 42), (243, 243, 243)]
Random color from palette:
(0, 137, 42)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for this, I know I was doing something wrong, great to be pointed in the right direction.